# How to display associated objects with links to their details page in Symfony 5 EasyAdmin 3?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin3

I have two entities, Offer and Candidate, with a OneToMany relationship between them. The relevant code parts are the followings:

In Offer.php:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Candidate::class, mappedBy="offer", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $candidates;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->candidates = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

In Candidate.php:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Offer::class, inversedBy="candidates")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $offer;
```

In OfferCrudController.php:

```
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            ArrayField::new('candidates', new TranslatableMessage('easyadmin.candidates'))
                ->onlyOnDetail(),
            AssociationField::new('candidates', new TranslatableMessage('easyadmin.candidates'))
                ->onlyOnIndex()
        ];
    }
```

In CandidateCrudController.php:

```
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            AssociationField::new('offer', new TranslatableMessage('easyadmin.candidate.offer'))
        ];
    }
```

My problem is that while in the case of Candidates EasyAdmin displays the Offer linked to its details page for each Candidate, for the Offers it displays only the non-clickable string representations of the Candidates, as the images show it:

[image: clickable Offers]

[image: non-clickable Candidates]

Is it possible to display the Candidates too with their appropriate links to their details page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you should create a custom template for this.
Let's say, you've created `/templates/admin/field/offer/detail/candidates.html.twig`. Then in `OfferCrudController` need to set created template for `candidates` field*:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    // ...
    yield AssociationField::new('candidates', 'Candidates')->onlyOnDetail()
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/offer/detail/candidates.html.twig');
}
```

- example with generator, but it can be easily written as array item, like in your example (instead ArrayField). I just prefer to use generator in that case, because that's more convenient to configure.

And in template just generate URL for each entity:

```
# /templates/admin/field/offer/detail/candidates.html.twig
{% if field.value is not empty %}
    {% for candidate in field.value %}
        {% set candidateDetailUrl = ea_url()
            .setController('App\\Controller\\Admin\\CandidateCrudController')
            .setAction(constant('EasyCorp\\Bundle\\EasyAdminBundle\\Config\\Action::DETAIL'))
            .setEntityId(candidate.id)
        %}
        <a href="{{ candidateDetailUrl }}" style="display: block">
            {{ candidate.name }}
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    No candidates
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Your answer will be very useful in other cases as well.